# Autocomplete form from a database

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project to autocomplete an address. I start by selecting a country. Once I have selected a country I want to only be able to select counties from that country. I want to be able to select the ID from the country chosen and send it in the url so the user can only select the counties in that country. If I change this $.getJSON("includes/county.php?countryId=" + countryId, req, function (data) to this $.getJSON("includes/county.php?countryId=" + 372, req, function (data) it works, but how do I input the id of the country into the countryId variable in the url?

```
//Country
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#country").autocomplete({
                //Defines the callback to format the results
                source: function (req, add) {
                    $.getJSON("includes/country.php", req, function (data) {
                        //Creates an array for results
                        var suggestions = [];
                        //Processes the response
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            suggestions.push(val);
                        });
                        //Pass thr array to callback
                        add(suggestions);
                    });
                },
                //Defines the select handler
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    $("#country").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });

        //Selecting the county
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#county").autocomplete({
                //Defines the callback to format the results
                source: function (req, add) {
                    $.getJSON("includes/county.php?countryId=" + countryId, req, function (data) {
                        //Creates an array for results
                        var suggestions = [];
                        //Processes the response
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            suggestions.push(val);
                        });
                        //Pass thr array to callback
                        add(suggestions);
                    });
                },
                //Defines the select handler
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    $("#county").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
```

The html form:

```
<div class="field">
                <label id="countryLabel">Country: </label>
                <div id="friends" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label id="countyLabel">County: </label>
                <div id="friends" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <input type="text" name="county" id="county">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Country.php file:

```
<?php
require_once("database.php");
$country = $_GET["term"];

if ($country != null) {
$queryCountry = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country LIKE :country";
$statement = $db->prepare($queryCountry);
$statement->bindValue(":country", $country."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {
    $statement->execute();
}
catch(PharException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

$countries = array();

foreach ($results as $result){
    $countries[$result['id']] = $result['country'];
}
$response = json_encode($countries);
echo $response;
}
```

County.php file:

```
<?php
require_once("database.php");
$countryId = $_GET["countryId"];
$county = $_GET["term"];

if ($county != null) {
$queryCounty = "SELECT * FROM counties WHERE name LIKE '$county%' AND     country_id = '$countryId'";
$statement = $db->prepare($queryCounty);
$statement->bindValue(":county", $county."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {
    $statement->execute();
}
catch(PharException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

$counties = array();

foreach ($results as $result){
    $counties[$result['id']] = $result['name'];
}
$response = json_encode($counties);
echo $response;
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to try onchange page reload with parameter or save in hidden input field